# How to pass an environment to an Rcpp chunk with knitr?

Tags: r, knitr, rcpp

I'm trying to take the following code and translate it into a knitr chunk (borrowed from the Rcpp examples):

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

openMPCode <- '
   std::vector<double> x = Rcpp::as<std::vector< double > >(xs);
   size_t n = x.size();
   #pragma omp parallel for shared(x, n)
   for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
     x[i] = ::log(x[i]);
   }
   return Rcpp::wrap(x);
'

## modify the plugin for Rcpp to support OpenMP
settings <- getPlugin("Rcpp")
settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS <- paste('-fopenmp', settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS)
settings$env$PKG_LIBS <- paste('-fopenmp -lgomp', settings$env$PKG_LIBS)
funOpenMP <- rcpp(signature(xs="numeric"), body=openMPCode, settings=settings)
```

Essentially, the main problem is ensuring that the environment gets passed into the knitr chunk, so that the `PKG_LIBS` and `PKG_CXXFLAGS` are set appropriately when the code is compiled. An example of what the `knitr` chunk might look like:

````
```{r engine='Rcpp'}
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector openmp_log( NumericVector x ) {
  size_t n = x.size();
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for( size_t i=0; i < n; i++ ) {
    x[i] = ::log10( x[i] );
  }
  return x;
}
```
````

If I understand correctly, knitr uses `sourceCpp` on whatever's in the chunk to compile it, and passes options specified in `engine.opts` to `sourceCpp`. Hence, I imagine there are two potential avenues:

1. setting `engine.opts=list(env=...)` so an appropriate environment is passed; however, I get an error trying this (formal argument "env" matched by multiple actual arguments).
2. A hook / custom chunk option could be used to set the environment, but I'm not sure how this could be done exactly.

This is with knitr 1.0.11 and Rcpp 0.10.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not realize users would pass a custom environment to the `Rcpp` engine, so I passed a default environment to the `env` argument in `sourceCpp()`. Now I [have removed](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/b600f7fe8cfd265726f3d9e8ae0c2c1c361ce162) the restriction. You can install the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme) on Github.

`PKG_LIBS` mentioned by Dirk should be a different problem here.

Comment: Nice. Double fix, as Rcpp in SVN now also addresses the issue I mentioned in my reply.

Answer (score 1):

We happen to have realized today that the `PKG_LIBS` treatment is buggy: overwrites instead of attempts. So I fear this currently does not work with Rcpp Attributes.

You could switch to using a package, or setting your compile etc flags somewhere else.

*Edit Feb 16* This is now fixed in SVN.